# Optuna, change axes ratio in plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, optuna

I've been running some optimization with optuna, and I'd like to produce plots with the same scale on both axes, but so far I was unable to find out how.

```py
study = optuna.create_study(study_name=study_name,
                            storage=f"sqlite:///{results_folder}/{study_name}.db",
                            directions=["maximize", "maximize"],
                            load_if_exists=True)
# I tried either
fig_pareto = optuna.visualization.plot_pareto_front(study, target_names=['precision', 'recall'])
fig_pareto.show()

# or
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
optuna.visualization.matplotlib.plot_pareto_front(study, target_names=['precision', 'recall']) 
ax.axis("equal")
ax.set_xlim(0.7, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0.7, 1)
target_names=['precision', 'recall'])
plt.savefig("some_name.png")
```

but without success.
This is what the saved plot looks like:

[image]

With the first method, the pictures open in an interactive view in the browser and I can resize them, but there's no option to precisely make them square.

When using the second way, it looks like calling:

```
optuna.visualization.matplotlib.plot_pareto_front(study, target_names=['precision', 'recall'])
```

is not linking the produced plot to the ax object?
If I do:

```
pareto_plot = optuna.visualization.matplotlib.plot_pareto_front(study, target_names=['precision', 'recall'])
```

the pareto_plot is an AxesSubplot object, can I manually load it in the axes?

Comment: `ax.axis('equal')`, but after you finish plotting, not before

Comment: Tried that, but the plot always looks the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had the answer right there.
I had to do:

```
pareto = optuna.visualization.matplotlib.plot_pareto_front(study, target_names=['precision', 'recall'])
pareto.axis('equal')
plt.savefig("pareto_plot.png")
```

Comment: How is that different from what I recommended?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! The problem was that I was applying the methods axis("equal")/set_xlim/set_ylim to the ax object (created by fig, ax = plt.subplots()), while I was supposed to apply them to the object created by optuna.visualization.matplotlib.plot_pareto_front. Maybe you meant that as well, and I misunderstood your comment?